# Is It right sentence in terms of grammar?

Tags: present-perfect

In what way can I rewrite the sentence if the sentence isn't right?

> She has never **skiied** on this mountain.

or

> She has never been **skiing** on this mountain.

She has never **skiing** on this mountain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She has never **skiied** on this mountain.
>   She has never **been skiing** on this mountain.

are both correct, *been skiing* is correct since your are on *this* mountain, however if it was a mountain you are not on, you might say

> She has never **gone skiing** on *that* mountain.

However, your final sentence

> She has never skiing on this mountain

is not correct.